# Remove an item from a checkbox list by its value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I would like to remove an item from the checkbox list using its value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk0" value ="Chicken">
$("#chk0:checkbox[value='Chicken']").parent().remove();
```

I am trying to remove the item but it is not working. I need some assistance.

Comment: Why are you spacing everything out? `value="Chicken"` is much easier to read than `value = "Chicken"`.

Comment: works without those spaces:  http://jsfiddle.net/JY4js/

Answer (score 2):

If `"#chk0"` is your container. You will need to use

```
$("#chk0 :checkbox[value = 'Chicken']").parent().remove();
```

Note the space between the id and the `:checkbox`

Otherwise you will look for a checkbox with id ="chk0" instead of the checkbox inside of your container.

But if the `#chk0` is the id for the input it will work fine..

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/NpXW4/1/)

Comment: `#chk0` is the ID of the checkbox. The markup is already within the question. Furthermore, this should have been a comment.

Comment: I answered before the question was edited and I saw only the value of the checkbox i didn't realized that the id was for the checkbox because it was plain text , that's why i put "If "#chk0" is your container. You will need to use" But thanks I will be more careful the next time

Comment: Thanks everyone. I figured it out.